# regex remove short sentences callouts

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all short sentences (callouts) from a string. See my example below. I want to remove all highlighted text. Maybe text < 25 characters that end with "." [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will target sentenses with a max length of 25.

```
/(?<=^|\.)\s*.{1,25}?\./gms
```

**Test snippet :**

```js
const regex = /(?<=^|\.)\s*.{1,25}?\./gms;
const str = `This is a test.  Keep this longer text that has over 25 characters.  Remove this small text.  `;

const result = str.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result);
```

Or without a look-behind.  For the browsers that stay behind.

```
/(^|\.)\s*.{1,25}?\./gms
```

Substitute with first capture group.

```js
const regex = /(^|\.)\s*.{1,25}?\./gms;
const str = `This is a test.  Keep this longer text that has over 25 characters.  
Remove this small text.  `;

const result = str.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Cool, but lookbehind is not supported yet by safari, if it's client side Javascript it won't work.

Comment: @Cubix48 Okay,  included a solution for that as well.

Comment: @LukStorms But what if two short sentences are next to each other ?

Comment: @LukStorms You can just replace the lookbehind in the first regex with a lookahead : ``/(^|\.)\s*.{1,25}?(?=\.)/gms``.

Comment: @Cubix48 True. But I kinda find it more intuitive that it captures the dot at the end of a sentence, since it's part of it. And if there's only 1 short sentence it'll end up with a dot. But yeah, that should work in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one helps. I didn't consider the '.' char
Because I populated this sentence in JS.

```js
const sentence = (() => {
    const sentences = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        const len = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 15 + 1) + 15);
        const sentence = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        sentence.push(String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97 + 1) + 97)));
        }
        sentences.push(sentence.join(''));
    }
    return sentences
    })();

    console.log(sentence.length)
    console.log(sentence)
    console.log(sentence.filter(s => s.length > 24))
    console.log(sentence.filter(s => s.length > 24).length)
```